Conversion human key point from 2d to 3d using realsense depth camera d400 and yolov8 pose
| Camera Model | D400 |
| Language | Python|
| Segment | Depth camera |
I am trying to map a person's pose in 3D using a depth camera and an algorithm that returns the person's joints in 2D. I have managed to extract the keypoints of interest, but when I try to calculate them in 3D using this function and then plot them, I get incorrect graphs. The inputs are xx and yy representing the pixel, with the origin point being the top-left corner. Is there an error in the function, or is the camera unable to accurately distinguish the depth of the keypoints? Do you have any advice?
In the function, I also implemented a selection of the pixel near the keypoint with the lowest depth in order to distinguish the person from the background.
def calculate_3d(x, y, depth_frame, intrinsics, w, h, window_size=30):
    min_depth = float('inf')

# Iterate over the pixels within the circular window around the keypoint
for i in range(-window_size // 2, window_size // 2 + 1):
    for j in range(-window_size // 2, window_size // 2 + 1):
        # Calculate the coordinates of the current pixel
        x_pixel = int(x) + i
        y_pixel = int(y) + j

        # Check if the current pixel is within the image bounds
        if 0 <= x_pixel < w and 0 <= y_pixel < h:
            # Get the depth value at the current pixel
            depth = depth_frame.get_distance(x_pixel, y_pixel)

            # Update the minimum depth value if the current depth is valid and smaller than the current minimum
            if depth != 0 and depth < min_depth:
                min_depth = depth

# If no valid depth value is found within the circular window, return zeros for all coordinates and angles
if min_depth == float('inf'):
    return 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

x_normalized = (x - intrinsics.ppx) / intrinsics.fx
y_normalized = (y - intrinsics.ppy) / intrinsics.fy

# Compute 3D point coordinates
x_3d = min_depth * x_normalized
y_3d = min_depth * y_normalized
z_3d = np.sqrt(min_depth**2 - x_3d**2 - y_3d**2) if min_depth > 0 else 0  

return x_3d, y_3d, z_3d, min_depth




please clarify, how do you expect to estimate Z for some pixel/coordinate in the image?

I solved my problems by averaging the depths acquired by the camera.
Unfortunately, it is not always accurate, so I had some errors.
To convert from 2D to 3D, I used s2_deproject_pixel_to_point.
